# Sonar users limit GitLab project visibility

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube v9.7.0.61563 (self-managed). I have integrated SonarQube with GitLab (self-managed). The users can log in to SonarQube using GitLab. All projects in SonarQube have been set up using GitLab.

Currently, a logged-in user can view all the projects in SonarQube, even the projects that he is not a member of in GitLab. Is there a way the user can view only those projects that he is a part of in GitLab?

I tried looking for the permissions in the Permission Template, however, I did not find anything related to GitLab project visibility.

Comment: you can use sonarqube's api to sync project visibility and user permissions, write a scheduled job  for example.